# How to put cloudwatch logs to firehouse stream using CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

In according to this [article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-logging-to-kinesis.html) we can send aws api gateway logs to Kinesis Data Firehose. I need to set it up in my CDK project. What I am trying to do:

```
export class MyStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
    this.createStreamBuffer();  //successful 
    this.createApi();
  }
  private createApi = () => {
      this.api = new RestApi(this, 'someName', {
      deploy: false,
      restApiName: "someName",
      apiKeySourceType: ApiKeySourceType.HEADER,
       deployOptions: {
        accessLogDestination: this.streamBuffer, //it doesn't work!
        accessLogFormat: AccessLogFormat.jsonWithStandardFields()
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to assigne kinesis stream as destination of api gateway?
I didn't find any samples and anything valuable in docs...